# Existence of limit of events from convergence in distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $(X_{n})_{n\geq 1}$ be a real-valued stochastic process and $(a_{n})_{n\geq 1}$ a real valued sequence. Suppose for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}
\mathbb{P}(X_n-a_{n}\leq x)=F(x) \quad (*)
$$
for some differentiable cdf $F$. Can I deduce the limit
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\{X_n-a_{n}\leq x\}
$$
exists?

Attempt: Firstly I don't see how to construct a monotone sequence from the sets $A_n=\{X_n-a_{n}\leq x\}$ (i.e. $A_{n}\subset A_{n+1}$ or $A_{n+1}\subset A_{n})$, so I'll attempt a contradiction.

Suppose $\{\omega\in \Omega:\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}X_{n}(\omega)-a_{n}\leq x\}$ does not exist. Note this rules out for each $\omega$ 
$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}X_{n}(\omega)-a_{n}>x$ as then the limit of $A_n$ is the empty set (although this would contradict $F(x)>0$).

Thus for each $\omega$, $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}X_{n}(\omega)-a_{n}$ does not exist. This should imply the statement $(*)$ is meaningless but I'm not sure how to finish?

Comment: Does $\{X_n-a_n\leq x\}$ mean $\{x : X_n-a_n\leq x\}$? How is a limit of sets defined? What happens in the case $X_n$ are i.i.d $\mathrm{Uniform}(0,1)$ variables and $a_1=a_2=\cdots=0$ for example?

Comment: $\{X_{n}-a_{n}\leq x\}=\{\omega\in \Omega:X_{n}(\omega)-a_{n}\leq x\}$ where $\Omega$ is the sample space. The limit set is defined to be $\{\omega\in \Omega: \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \mathbb{I}_{A_n}(\omega)=1\}.$ Let me think about the Uniform case.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by a sequence of sets $A_n$ converging - do you perhaps mean $\bigcap_n\bigcup_{k\ge n}A_k=\bigcup_n\bigcap_{k\ge n}A_k$? - but regardless of what you mean, why would you expect this result to be true? Convergence in law says very little about the random variables in question. If you had almost sure convergence, you might be able to show something, but you would need a careful definition of what you mean for sets to converge.

Comment: I do mean that $\limsup A_{n}=\liminf A_{n}$ as you say. I don't want to say anything about the random variables in question. I'm asking, as $\mathbb{P}(A_n) \rightarrow c$ can I ever say $A=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}A_n$ exists and $\mathbb{P}(A)=c$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The limit won't exist in general. The most permissive definition I can think of for convergence of events $A_n$ would be that $\limsup A_n \setminus \liminf A_n$ is a null set. In other words,

$$\mathbb P[\text{$A_n$ and $\overline{A_n}$ each occur infinitely often}]=0.$$

In your case, with $A_n$ being the event $X_n-a_n\leq x$, it is easy to see that this probability can be $1$. For example take $X_n$ to be i.i.d standard normal, and $a_n=0$ for all $n$, and $x=0$. Then $A_n$ and $\overline{A_n}$ both occur infinitely often with probability $1$ (e.g. by the strong law of large numbers, with probability $1$, the proportion $|\{n\leq N : A_n\text{ holds}\}|/N$ tends to $\tfrac 1 2$ as $N\to \infty$).

This could be seen as just an analogue of the usual situation that convergence in distribution does not imply convergence almost surely. It's just that the topology here is generated by $(-\infty,x]$ and $(x,+\infty)$ instead of all open intervals.